# Geometric series sum recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I have to write an algorithm that will compute the sum of `a + a r + a r**2 + ... + a r**(n-1)` recursively. I am very new to recursion and am having trouble wrapping my head around using three different variables while only using one recursively. Any help is greatly appreciated.

wrote this but computes a wrong answer.

```py
def recursiveSum(a,r,n):
    if n == 0:
        return a
    elif n == 1:
        return a + r
    else:
        theSum = a + ((recursiveSum(a,r,n-1) * r))
        return theSum
```

Comment: format your code..

Comment: If `n == 1` you return `a + r`. Why? Look at the sum you want to compute and you'll notice it's not `a + r`.

Comment: How did you get the recursive formula `theSum = a + ((recursiveSum(a,r,n-1) * r))`? It's not correct.

Answer (score 2):

First I'll define `recursiveSum(a, r, n) = a + ar + ar^2 + ... + ar^n` as it turns out a bit easier to work with.  Before writing any code, it's usually worth making sure we have our step and base cases correct for our recursive function.  We can't go any simpler than the one term case (with n = 0):

```
recursiveSum(a, r, 0) = a
```

And so this makes sense as a base case.  Next, we see that (for n > 0):

```
a + ar + ar^2 + ... + ar^n = a + r(a + ar + ar^2 + ... + ar^(n - 1))
```

In other words:

```
recursiveSum(a, r, n + 1) = a + r*recursiveSum(a, r, n)
```

Now, we can determine the result for all `a, r, n` using only these two cases.  We're now in a position to write an implementation:

```py
def recursiveSum(a, r, n):
    if n == 0:
        return a
    else: 
        return a + recursiveSum(a, r, n - 1) * r
```

It's also worth noting that there exists a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) for the sum of the first n terms in a geometric series, so we can compute this sum much faster if need be.